# Why do I have memory leaks in a program that does nothing (with Valgind on mac OS 10.13.6)?

Tags: macos, memory, valgrind

I just installed valgrind on my macbook with brew, and I tested it with this:

```
int main(void)
{
    return (0);
}
```

Here is the command:

> valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full ./test_leaks

And the output:

```
==736== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==736== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==736== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==736== Command: ./test_leaks
==736==
==736==
==736== HEAP SUMMARY:
==736==     in use at exit: 18,245 bytes in 162 blocks
==736==   total heap usage: 183 allocs, 21 frees, 26,693 bytes allocated
==736==
==736== 64 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 14 of 39
==736==    at 0x1000AB6EA: calloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.14.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==736==    by 0x100758B9A: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100758C50: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100758C50: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x10075732B: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100755A9D: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1007684E0: map_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100006C64: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x100006E39: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x10022071D: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100755073: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1001AAB34: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==736==
==736== 64 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 15 of 39
==736==    at 0x1000AB6EA: calloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.14.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==736==    by 0x100758B9A: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100758C50: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100758C50: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100758C50: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x10075732B: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100755A9D: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1007684E0: map_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100006C64: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x100006E39: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x10022071D: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100755073: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==
==736== 64 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 16 of 39
==736==    at 0x1000AB6EA: calloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.14.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==736==    by 0x100758B9A: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100758C68: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100758C50: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100758C50: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100758C50: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x10075732B: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100755A9D: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1007684E0: map_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100006C64: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x100006E39: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x10022071D: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==736==
==736== 64 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 17 of 39
==736==    at 0x1000AB6EA: calloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.14.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==736==    by 0x100758B9A: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100758C68: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100758C50: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100758C50: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x10075732B: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100755A9D: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1007684E0: map_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100006C64: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x100006E39: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x10022071D: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100755073: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==
==736== 72 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 18 of 39
==736==    at 0x1000AB6EA: calloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.14.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==736==    by 0x1007557C2: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1007684E0: map_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100006C64: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x100006E39: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x10022071D: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100755073: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1001AAB34: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1001AAB1B: libdispatch_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1000B99C2: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100018AC5: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x100018CF5: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==
==736== 80 (32 direct, 48 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 19 of 39
==736==    at 0x1000AB2FE: malloc_zone_malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.14.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==736==    by 0x100757ABF: NXCreateHashTableFromZone (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100757A6E: NXCreateHashTable (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100757948: NXCreateMapTableFromZone (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1007578D3: NXCreateMapTable (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100756394: __sel_registerName(char const*, int, int) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100756096: sel_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x10075598C: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1007684E0: map_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100006C64: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x100006E39: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x10022071D: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==736==
==736== 144 (32 direct, 112 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 22 of 39
==736==    at 0x1000AB2FE: malloc_zone_malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.14.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==736==    by 0x100757A9E: NXCreateHashTableFromZone (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100757A6E: NXCreateHashTable (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100757948: NXCreateMapTableFromZone (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1007578D3: NXCreateMapTable (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100756394: __sel_registerName(char const*, int, int) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100756096: sel_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x10075598C: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1007684E0: map_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100006C64: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x100006E39: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x10022071D: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==736==
==736== 192 bytes in 3 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 23 of 39
==736==    at 0x1000AB6EA: calloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.14.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==736==    by 0x100758B9A: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100758C50: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x10075732B: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100755A9D: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1007684E0: map_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100006C64: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x100006E39: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x10022071D: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100755073: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1001AAB34: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1001AAB1B: libdispatch_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==736==
==736== 192 bytes in 3 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 24 of 39
==736==    at 0x1000AB6EA: calloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.14.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==736==    by 0x100758B9A: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100758C68: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100758C50: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x10075732B: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100755A9D: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1007684E0: map_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100006C64: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x100006E39: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x10022071D: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100755073: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1001AAB34: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==736==
==736== 3,264 bytes in 51 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 37 of 39
==736==    at 0x1000AB6EA: calloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.14.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==736==    by 0x100758B9A: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100758C68: realizeClass(objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x10075732B: _read_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100755A9D: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1007684E0: map_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100006C64: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x100006E39: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x10022071D: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100755073: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1001AAB34: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1001AAB1B: libdispatch_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==736==
==736== 4,136 (24 direct, 4,112 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 39 of 39
==736==    at 0x1000AB2FE: malloc_zone_malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.14.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==736==    by 0x100757901: NXCreateMapTableFromZone (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1007578D3: NXCreateMapTable (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100756394: __sel_registerName(char const*, int, int) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100756096: sel_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x10075598C: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1007684E0: map_images (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100006C64: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x100006E39: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==736==    by 0x10022071D: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==736==    by 0x100755073: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==736==    by 0x1001AAB34: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==736==
==736== LEAK SUMMARY:
==736==    definitely lost: 3,992 bytes in 64 blocks
==736==    indirectly lost: 6,864 bytes in 7 blocks
==736==      possibly lost: 72 bytes in 3 blocks
==736==    still reachable: 32 bytes in 1 blocks
==736==         suppressed: 7,285 bytes in 87 blocks
==736== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==736== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==736==
==736== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==736== ERROR SUMMARY: 11 errors from 11 contexts (suppressed: 12 from 12)
```

For readability, only the leaks:

```
==736== LEAK SUMMARY:
==736==    definitely lost: 3,992 bytes in 64 blocks
==736==    indirectly lost: 6,864 bytes in 7 blocks
==736==      possibly lost: 72 bytes in 3 blocks
==736==    still reachable: 32 bytes in 1 blocks
==736==         suppressed: 7,285 bytes in 87 blocks
```

I first used valgrind on a project I am working on, but since it had 0 leak the last time (on an other mac), I thought it was a bit strange. I reinstalled valgrind a couple of times, tried with the most basic program I could come up with, and here we are.

Although I already programmed on mac OS, I am relatively new to it. Is this normal behaviour ? Or do I have to fix this somehow ?

EDIT:

So this took a little work, but I finally managed to remove "unwanted" errors. I wrote a script that takes a command into input, passes it through valgrind and stores every leak generated in a suppression file. This is a list of known leaks that valgrind will simply not show when encountered (more info about it [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress) and [there](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Valgrind_Suppression_File_Howto)). This is hacky, but it kind of resolves my problem.

This solution is obvioulsy not optimal though. Now each time I will see a leak I will have to manually check if it is from my program or if this a system library leak I did not already encounter.

If somebody has a less hacky solution, I'd be glad to here it. But for the time being here is the [script](https://github.com/Taiwing/valsup) if you have the same problem (be careful and check the valsup file first, especially if you already have a ".valgrindrc" file in your home directory). This includes a perl script (that you can find at the end of [this page](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Parse_valgrind_suppressions.sh)), which parses valgrind output to get the suppressions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Memory Leaks using Valgrind in /usr/lib/dyld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505729/memory-leaks-using-valgrind-in-usr-lib-dyld)

Comment: This is Valgrind bug on macos, see my answer to similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/47509670/72178.